# How to parse comments, gifts from TikTok live streams?

Tags: parsing, tiktok

How to parse live data (comments, gifts) from TikTok live streams? I have already seen games on streams that react to comments or gifts, but I could not find a solution how to do it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

How to parse is a bit of complex question. For that you have to closely observe TikTok official services and public live stream data so that you can reverse engineer a way to find the way.

But I think your real intention here is to parse that data and then do some thing creative with it. And for that there are available SDKs around. This [TikTok Live Connector](https://github.com/zerodytrash/TikTok-Live-Connector) gives you parsed live event data like comments and gifts so that you can continue your part.

Cheers mate! Happy coding. Hope this helps for anyone looking :)